# SQL Server 2008 - How to Join 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008:

I have 3 tables

```
Users, Scores, Lessons
```

`Users` & `Scores` are linked by `StudentID`

`Scores` & `Lessons` are linked by `LessonID`

I want to display the scores for a `StudentID`. Here are the columns I want to display

```
Users.Name, Scores.LessonID, Scores.Result, Lessons.Title
```

I know how to Join the 2 tables. How do I throw in the 3rd table?

Comment: Check how to [Retrieve Data from Multiple Tables with SQL Joins](http://databases.about.com/od/careers/l/aajoins1.htm) -From About.com

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Same way as one table:

```
SELECT Users.Name, Scores.LessonID, Scores.Result, Lessons.Title
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Scores ON Users.StudentID = Scores.StudentID
INNER JOIN Lessons On Scores.LessonID = Lessons.LessonID
```

Comment: If you add the `dbo.` prefix to your tables (always recommended) and start using table aliases to make your query more readable - this would be the perfect answer!

Comment: Sure, but none of those things were the question.

Comment: true. But marc offered you some tips to improve yourself, and by raising the quality of your answers, the question asker and all future viewers learn more, too.

Comment: It also detracts from the point of the answer. I don't want to give off the wrong impression that adding `dbo.` or using aliases is what causes the solution to work. There is plenty of other content that caters to those specific issues. If we're going to put in everything, he might as well just go read an SQL book.

Comment: You should try to model best practices in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   T1
   INNER JOIN T2
     ON T2.C = T1.C
   INNER JOIN T3
              LEFT JOIN T4
                ON T4.C = T3.C
     ON T3.C = T2.C 


is equivalent to (T1 Inner Join T2)  Inner Join (T3 Left Join T4)
```